Delay elements on particular GroupedFlux among others
I'm having a code similar to this:
@Test
void shouldSlowdownOnlyEvens() {
    final Flux<Integer> globalFlux = Flux.range(1, 20000)
            .groupBy(number -> number % 2 == 0)
            .flatMap(this::dispatch);

    StepVerifier.create(globalFlux)
            .expectNextCount(20000)
            .verifyComplete();
}

private Publisher<? extends Integer> dispatch(GroupedFlux<Boolean, Integer> groupedFlux) {
    return groupedFlux.key() ?
            // even flux
            groupedFlux
                    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println) :
            groupedFlux.doOnNext(System.out::println);
}

In the real code, "Flux.range(1, 20000)" is a Flux generated by a Kafka consumer of multiple topics.
With this code, I want to slow down Even numbers Flux, and keep the Odd numbers Flux propagating with the same frequency.
The using "delayElements" like this, would slow down the whole Flux together. delaySequence too, but with consuming-bunch-of-numbers-at-once flavor.
The previous code shows:

Which means (it printed odd numbers until 513, then it starts alternating between evens and odds till the end, taking one second to print each couple. Any hints please?

The problem here stems from your groupBy hanging, as per the documentation:

The groups need to be drained and consumed downstream for groupBy to work correctly. Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed downstream (eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that is set too low).

(emphasis mine)
Looking at the groupBy-code, it configures prefetch of Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE which defaults to 256 unless explicitly specified.
Since you produce two groups, one that is draining instantly and the other that is not draining at all until the specified delay, when your sequence reaches 512 elements, the groupBy "hangs" until the downstream subscriber that is not draining their group (the delayElements one) starts draining, which it does after the delay. However, it basically keeps the groupBy buffer constantly full (256), which affects the other group as the groupBy won't request(n) more from upstream until the slow group drains its elements.
Solving this is easy but has various implications depending on what size of data your real code is actually working with.
Using onBackpressureBuffer will request(unbounded) from the upstream GroupedFlux, so the group will be properly drained and buffered. This operator has some implications, namely that the buffer can grow unbounded, leading to high memory usage or OOM errors if the data is large and/or there is a huge burst of data that is not processed fast enough downstream.
An adjustment of your code using this operator:
private Publisher<? extends Integer> dispatch(GroupedFlux<Boolean, Integer> groupedFlux) {
    return groupedFlux.key() ?
            // even flux
            groupedFlux
                    .onBackpressureBuffer()
                    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println) :
            groupedFlux.doOnNext(System.out::println);
}

delayElements is particularly dangerous to use with this operator, as it effectively downclocks the stream to a fixed rate. In your case, you will have a rate of 1Hz (1 element per second), and if the upstream rate is consistently above 1Hz, this buffer will grow indefinitely until OOM. delaySequence is better as it doesn't downclock the rate of the stream, it just offsets it into the future. You should take some time to consider which one you really want to use.
If you want the behaviour of delayElements, it is also a good idea to use one of the overloads of onBackpressureBuffer that lets you specify a maximum buffer size (unbounded buffers is the root of all evil) and decide on a strategy to use if this buffer overflows.
You can also use some of the bufferXX-operators to achieve something similar, but with more control, e.g bufferWhile.
It's also worth mentioning that since the real source is Kafka, if you have the possibility to use a separate consumer for these topics, you can separate the handling of them and avoid that they affect each other.
